# Modify the buffer name in the modeline

Tags: mode-line, powerline, mode-line-format

Helm-mini displays a yellow `@` when a file or buffer is remote (in my case accessed via tramp/ssh), which I find quite handy. I'd like to add such a marker to the buffer name part of my modeline, but I'm not sure what's the best way. I'm using `powerline`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a separate face, e.g., `my-remote-buf`, that you use to show remote buffers.
2. Set `mode-line-buffer-identification` to use that face when the buffer is remote:

   ```
   (setq mode-line-buffer-identification
         (list (propertize (car mode-line-buffer-identification)
                           'face 'my-remote-buf)))
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Would `rename-buffer` function be what you are looking for? You could use a hook to append @ to a buffer name if you'd like to do it automatically.